# Curl token request equivalent in Jersey

Tags: java, curl, jersey, token

I know this question have been asked a million times but I can't figure out what's wrong with my token request.

The command in curl is

> curl -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" -H
>   "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" -k -d
>   "grant_type=password&username=XXXXX&password=XXXXX"
>   https://localhost/sso/token

Converted to jersey it should be:

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://localhost/sso/token");
String appKey= "Basic  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
String input="grant_type=password&username=XXXXX&password=XXXXX";
    ClientResponse response = null; 
            response = webResource.
                    header("Authorization", appKey).
                    header("Content-Type", "/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8").
                    accept("application/json").
                    post(ClientResponse.class, input);




    if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                            + response.getStatus());
                }
                String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
                System.out.println("Server response .... \n");
                System.out.println(output);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }**
```

The answer I get:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 415    at
>   com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.jerseyclient.JerseyClientAccessToken.main(JerseyClientAccessToken.java:67)

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

is not the same of this:

```
Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
```

So you should change it. That's why you are getting a 415 error (Unsupported Media Type).